# Block signature for block that takes a function pointer and returns a block

Tags: c, clang, objective-c-blocks

I am using clang on linux.
What is the correct way to format this block?

```
(int ^(int, char**)) (^f2b)(int, char**) = (int ^(int, char**)) ((int (*func)(int, char**)))
{
  return int ^(int argc, char** argv){ func(argc, argv)};
};
```

I am getting an error

`error: type-id cannot have a name
int (^f2b)(int, char**) = (int ^(int, char**)) ((int (*func)(int, char**)))`

The error underlines (*func).

I am trying to create a block that takes in a function pointer named func as a parameter and returns a block that calls that func using the arguments it is passed.

Comment: @TypeIA it is "C"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala All right, maybe I'm about to learn something... what's up with the carets?

Comment: I think it is only technically "C". Blocks are a feature of clang https://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html I am trying to learn to use them because I like high order functions.

Comment: @TypeIA they're a Clang extension for blocks

Comment: In any case, `func` is a name that perhaps shouldn't be there.

Comment: @TypeIA I believe the ^ (carets) denote a block pointer instead of a function pointer. I thought they would have the same syntax.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I was trying to use ```func``` as the parameter name. The parameter is suppose to be a function pointer. I am struggling with the syntax.

Comment: I see, thanks for the lesson. I'd not come across that feature of clang. I suppose the tags are perfect then.

Comment: You've declared a block that takes an `int` and a `char **` and returns an `int`. And then you've initialized it with mush. Which is to say that I'm as confused as the compiler. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @user3386109 I am trying to make an auto block wrapper for functions with the type signature (int, char**). 

I want a call to f2b(a_function) to return a block that just calls a_function with the parameters passed to it.

Comment: @user3386109 I meant to make a block that takes a function that takes an `int` and a `char **`

Comment: @SultanLegend I took my best guess, and posted an answer.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I don't know Objective-c, does the objective-c-blocks belong on this question? Is it that the code is valid objective-c or that this code uses capabilities that came directly from objective-c?

Comment: @SultanLegend: Blocks is a Clang feature that is almost entirely used in Objective-C, as an anonymous function and closure syntax for that language, and is used extensively in the Apple iOS and macOS APIs. Technically, Blocks are available in pure C too, when using Clang, but rarely does anyone use it in C. The term "Blocks" is ambiguous by itself, as the C syntax of using braces to group statements together can also be called "blocks", so "objective-c-blocks" is the best tag for this feature, even though it is technically available in pure C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the `Block_copy` function from `<Block.h>`<sup>1</sup>. That puts a copy of a block on the heap, which allows the block to be returned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Block.h>

typedef int (^block_t)(int, char **);
typedef int (*func_t)(int, char **);

block_t (^createBlock)(func_t func) = ^(func_t func)
{
    return Block_copy( ^(int argc, char **argv) { return func(argc, argv); } );
};

int showFirst(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return argc;
}

int main(void)
{
    int argc = 3;
    char *argv[] = {"hello", "world", NULL};

    block_t block1 = createBlock(showFirst);
    int count = block1(argc, argv);
    printf("count=%d\n", count);
    Block_release(block1);
}
```

`createBlock` takes a function pointer as its argument, and returns a block with the signature `int (^block)(int, char **)`.

`showFirst` is just one possible implementation of the function that can be passed to `createBlock`. It displays the first string in the `argv` array and returns the value in `argc`.

The `main` function creates a block from the `showfirst` function. It then invokes the block, prints the returned value, and releases the block.

The output from the code is:

> hello
>   count=3

---

<sup>1</sup> I was not aware of `<Block.h>` until reading OP's answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/ helped a lot.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Block.h>

int fake_main(int argc, char** words)
{
  printf("%s\n", (char*)words);
  return argc;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  typedef int(*main_type_func)(int, char**);
  typedef int(^main_type)(int, char**);
  typedef main_type(^f2b_type)(main_type_func);

  f2b_type f2b = ^ (main_type_func func)
    {
      return Block_copy(^ (int apple, char** ban)
      {
        return func(apple, ban);
      });
    };

  printf("%d\n", f2b(fake_main)(1, "words worked"));
}
```

This is a minimum example of accomplishing the goals I outlined in the question.

The trick is the typedefs. Simplify the type signature by creating typedefs to help. I recommend that you use these whenever you want to accept and/or return a function pointer/block pointer.

Block_copy() moves the block from the stack into the heap.

It would be more correct to save the block pointer returned from

```
f2b(fake_main)
```

Then after use call

```
Block_release()
```

On it.

Answer (score 1):

Your type syntax is incorrect. Based on your usage, I'm guessing you are declaring `f2b` to be a pointer to a block, which takes a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and a `char **` and returns an `int`, and the block returns another block that takes an `int` and a `char **` and returns an `int`.

The proper syntax for that declaration would be:

```
int (^(^f2b)(int (*) (int, char **)))(int, char **)
```

The syntax for more complicated C types is often counter-intuitive, especially in cases of multiple levels of functions and arrays.

The ever-useful cdecl.org website supports blocks: [declare f2b as block(pointer to function(int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int) returning block(int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int](https://cdecl.org/?q=declare+f2b+as+block%28pointer+to+function%28int%2C+pointer+to+pointer+to+char%29+returning+int%29+returning+block%28int%2C+pointer+to+pointer+to+char%29+returning+int) (they say "block" whereas I say "pointer to block")

Your block definition written out using full block literal syntax (including return types) would be something like this (remembering to copy the block in order to return it):

```
int (^(^f2b)(int (*) (int, char **)))(int, char **) =
^int (^(int (*func)(int, char **)))(int, char **) {
    return Block_copy(^int (int argc, char **argv) {
        return func(argc, argv);
    });
};
```

Return types may be omitted in block literals, so it could be written like:

```
int (^(^f2b)(int (*) (int, char **)))(int, char **) =
^(int (*func)(int, char **)) {
    return Block_copy(^(int argc, char **argv) {
        return func(argc, argv);
    });
};
```